# FragmentActivity TabHost with Fragment and Activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have to implement such diagram-hierarchy in my application.

[image: hierarchy]

I have got 5 tabs from `TabHost`. One of them should be `Activity` cause of specific behaviour. This only one Activity should have both: **landscape** and **portrait** orientation, but `Fragments` should have only one (portrait).

Every portrait layout should have tabs below, but this one Activity shouldn't. I managed do accomplish it with 5 fragments inside `TabHost`, but I found out, that I can do that only with one Activity and 4 Fragments, or with all 5 Activities.

It won't be a problem to have 5 activities (FragmentActivities), but I prefer to have Fragments. I think, that i should extend `FragmentActivity` and `TabActivity` in `MyTabActivity` (it is Activity with TabHost), but I cannot extend two classes in JAVA. Unlucky there's no such class like `TabFragmentActivity` :-)

So my question: **is it possible to obtain such effect like in the diagram above**?

PS Maybe I'm missing sth important, cause I have just started with Java/Android - it could be a clue.

Comment: you have solve this problem ?

Comment: No, because the requirements of application have changed. But the best solution shall be using Activities instead Fragments there - it makes it simple to resolve (simple change in manifest for activity makes orientation the way we like). But thank you for attention :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a solution to solve your problem here:
http://droidapp.co.uk/2012/05/25/android-dev-actionbarsherlock-tabs-viewpager/
and here the source code:
https://bitbucket.org/owentech/abstabsviewpager/

wich is

It's a tutorial to work with actionbar, tabs, viewpager and fragments...and supporting >2.3, so it seems to solve all your needs.